# Jest mocking a mongodb record in a service

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to test a service in Nestjs which is responsible for getting one record out of a mongo database, using Jest.

As per common convention, when writing unit tests that test services we can mock a record that would sit in a database.

I'm trying the following implementation:

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { QuestionsService } from './questions.service';
import { CreateQuestionRequestDto } from './dto/create-question-request.dto';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UpdateQuestionRequestDto } from './dto/update-question-request.dto';
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DuplicateQuestionRequestDto } from './dto/duplicate-question-request.dto';

const testQuestion: CreateQuestionRequestDto = {
    data: {
        createdBy: { id: 0, name: '' },
        lanugageTexts: undefined,
        options: undefined,
        status: undefined,
        type: undefined,
        entityId: 1,
        propertyId: 'propHash1',
        companyId: 1,
        entityType: 'announcement',
    },
};

describe('QuestionsService', () => {
    let questionService: QuestionsService;
    let findOne: jest.Mock;
    let findOneAndUpdate: jest.Mock;
    let find: jest.Mock;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        // save = jest.fn();
        findOne = jest.fn();
        findOneAndUpdate = jest.fn();
        find = jest.fn();
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                QuestionsService,
                {
                    provide: getModelToken('Question'),
                    useValue: {}
                }
            ]
        })
        .compile();

        questionService = await module.get<QuestionsService>(QuestionsService);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(questionService).toBeDefined();
    });

    /**
     * Question Get
     */
    describe('when getting a question', () => {
        describe('and the questionId does not exist', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                findOne.mockReturnValue(undefined);
            })
            it('should throw a NotFound exception', async () => {
                const response = await questionService.get('announcement', 9136500000);

                expect(response).toThrow(NotFoundException);
            });
        });

        describe('and the questionId exists', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                findOne.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(testQuestion));
            });
            it('should update the correct question', async() => {
                const response = await questionService.get('announcement', 1);

                expect(response).toMatchObject(updatedTestQuestion);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When I run this test I get the following error message.

```
● QuestionsService › when getting a question › and the questionId does not exist › should throw a NotFound exception

    TypeError: this.questionModel.find is not a function

      52 |         const data: Question[] = [];
      53 |         const questions = await this.questionModel
    > 54 |             .find(
         |              ^
      55 |                 { entityType: entityType, entityId: entityId, status: QuestionStatus.ACTIVE },
      56 |                 { answers: 0 },
      57 |                 {

      at QuestionsService.get (questions/questions.service.ts:54:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (questions/questions.spec.ts:128:56)
```

The service method I'm testing is.

```
async get(entityType: string, entityId: number): Promise<any> {
        const data: Question[] = [];
        const questions = await this.questionModel
            .find(
                { entityType: entityType, entityId: entityId, status: QuestionStatus.ACTIVE },
                { answers: 0 },
                {
                    sort: { _id: -1 },
                    limit: 1,
                }
            )
            .exec();

        if (!questions.length) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        questions.forEach((question) => {
            data.push(question);
        });

        return { data };
    }
```

*find()* is the mongoose method that fetches the record from the database. I believe for the test I need to somehow include these methods I'm using in the service and mock them but I cannot find one clear answer.